# Add commas to Indian numbers using jQuery or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, numbers

I'm using d3 to visualize the data and i used this function to convert the numbers from Arabic Numbers to Indian Numbers (1 > ١)

```
    function arNum(numb){
    var str     = numb.toString();
    var arabic  = {"0" : '٠', "1": '١',"2": '٢',"3": '٣',"4": '٤',"5": '٥',"6": '٦',"7": '٧',"8": '٨',"9": '٩'};
    var chars   = str.split("");
    var newnum  = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {

        newnum[i] = arabic[ chars[i] ];
    }

    return newnum.join("");
}
```

and it is work very good then i want to add commas to separate numbers like that 1000 to 1,000 but i need it to be done using the Indian numbers like that ١,٠٠٠

so i used this function and it is working on the arabic number 123456789 but not on the indian numbers:

```
 function commaSeparateNumber(val){
    while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())){
      val = val.toString().replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/, '$1'+','+'$2');
    }
    return val;
  }
```

so any help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the commas to the Arabic numbers first, then convert to Indian ones.

I tried it in your JSfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/samehsubscription/F9zCK/ and it worked fine. Update the arNum function like below:

```
function arNum(numb){
    var str     = numb.toString();

    while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(str.toString())){
        str = str.toString().replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/, '$1'+','+'$2');
    }

    var arabic  = {"0" : '٠', "1": '١',"2": '٢',"3": '٣',"4": '٤',"5": '٥',"6": '٦',"7": '٧',"8": '٨',"9": '٩'};
   var chars   = str.split("");
    var newnum  = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        if(chars[i] == ",") newnum[i] = ",";
        else
        newnum[i] = arabic[ chars[i] ];
    }

    return newnum.join("");
}
```

Comment: Worked perfect (Y) :D thanx alot for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function or the ragex of this function according to your requirement:

```
Number.prototype.NumberFormat = function (decimals, decPoint, thousandsSep) {
    decPoint = typeof decPoint !== 'undefined' ? decPoint : '.';
    thousandsSep = typeof thousandsSep !== 'undefined' ? thousandsSep : ',';

    var parts = this.toFixed(decimals).toString().split('.');
    parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, thousandsSep);

    return parts.join(decPoint);
};

Just call 

val = val.toString().NumberFormat(2);
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/samehsubscription/F9zCK/

i tried to use it here but it didn't work !? so i removed it but if you can help by implement it here i will be so thankful for you d.value is the real numbers then i converted it using arNum() function